# TIMED_WAITING on message listener thread

Tags: activemq-artemis

I use ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1 and getting message listener thread hanging issue.
Thread is going into TIMED_WAITING and recover only after client JVM restart. This is an indeterminate issue and not able to reproduce easily. Client library version is 2.16.0.

````
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.waitCompletion(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:301)
    - locked <0x000000050cd4e4f0> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.saveBuffer(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:275)
    - locked <0x000000050cd4e4f0> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl.checkBuffer(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:159)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl.getBodyBuffer(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQBytesMessage.readBytes(ActiveMQBytesMessage.java:220)
    at com.eu.jms.JMSEventBus.onMessage(JMSEventBus.java:385)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ```
````

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue using the ActiveMQ Artemis last version (2.17.0) on server's side?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will try to upgrade Artemis latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client is waiting in `LargeMessageControllerImpl.waitCompletion`. This wait will *not* block forever. The code waits in a loop for packets of a [*large* message](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html). As long as packets of the large message are still arriving the client will continue to wait until all the packets have arrived or if a packet doesn't arrive within the given timeout it will throw an error. The timeout is based on the `callTimeout` which is configured on the client's URL. The default `callTimeout` is `30000` (i.e. 30 seconds).

My guess is that your client is receiving a very large message or the network has slown down or perhaps a combination of these things. You can [turn on TRACE logging](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html#activating-trace-for-a-specific-logger) for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl` to see the individual large message packets arriving at the client if you want more insight into what's happening.

To be clear, it's not surprising that thread dumps show your client waiting here as this is the most likely place for the code to be waiting while it receives a large message. It doesn't mean the client is stuck.

Keep in mind that if there is an actual network error or loss of connection the client will throw an error. Also, the client maintains an independent thread which sends & receives "ping" packets to & from the broker respectively. If the client doesn't get the expected ping response then it will throw an error as well. The fact that none of this happened with your client indicates the connection is valid.

I would recommend checking the size of the message at the head of the queue. The broker supports arbitrarily large messages so it could potentially be many gigs which the client will happily sit and receive as long as the connection is valid.

Comment: I suspected this as infinite blocking with properties such as 'Total Messages Acked' is zero for long time and very higher value in 'FirstMessageAge' for specific queue. Both properties monitored through Artemis web console.

Comment: Did you activate TRACE logging as described? If so, did you see any message packets flowing to the client while it was waiting? The 'Total Messages Acked' and 'FirstMessageAge' won't change until the message is fully received and acknowledged by the client.

Comment: Will try the mentioned log settings in our application. Is log too verbose or only for large message? And also this issue happen once in a month or two.  We waited close to one hour to check if 'Total Messages Acked' value change from zero. Any possibility to avoid this issue if we upgrade Artemis version to latest ( 2.17.0)?.

Comment: Full TRACE logging would be too verbose, but if you just enable it for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl` then I think it should be OK since it's only used in 2 places. I can't say if you can avoid this issue by upgrading since I don't know what the underlying issue is or even if it really is an "issue" and not just a really big message or slow network, etc.

Comment: Did not get the issue after recent incident. But if issue happen during operational time, manual restart of client application is a challenge. Will do the log settings as per your suggestion. In `LargeMessageControllerImpl.waitCompletion` method, by some reason with network issue and 'streamEned' is false, how timeout exception happen with 'timeWait' value as zero.

Comment: Also please suggest any additional settings I need to look like timeout or some specific to LargeMessageHandling.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Actually I was going through the logic in `LargeMessageControllerImpl.waitCompletion`. Not sure thread stuck at `wait` state as the `readTimeout` is 30 seconds. Any chance it is looping in while condition with `streamEnded` value as false? Next time I will take heap dump to check the variable states.

Comment: It is certainly looping in the `while` loop, and it is certainly waiting in `wait`. The thread dump says it is on [line 301 of `LargeMessageControllerImpl.java` which is calling `wait`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.16.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/client/impl/LargeMessageControllerImpl.java#L301).

Comment: I assume if there is network error in between, it should fail and throw some error. If the large message size too high, this situation can happen? But I waited around one hour  when it occurred last time and restarted client application.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your latest comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. `_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE` from `FirstMessageAsJson` using Artemis console should be fine?

Comment: `FirstMessageAsJson` won't give you what you need. You should use `listDeliveringMessagesAsJSON` instead since the message will be "in delivery" to the client.

Comment: I got the same issue again. Same stack trace pointing to large message. But noticed that delivering message is not large message,  checked from ```listDeliveringMessagesAsJSON```.

Comment: You would have to inspect the results of `listDeliveringMessagesAsJSON` *while* the client was stalled. Is that what you did? Once the exception occurs it's too late to look as the message which was being delivered will be cancelled back to the queue due to the client's failure (i.e. it won't be in delivery anymore). In any event, a non-large message shouldn't be treated as a large message so that would definitely be a bug. If you're convinced this is what is happening then you need to reproduce on the latest release and file an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS).

Comment: Yes I checked from ```listDeliveringMessagesAsJSON``` only. ```messageID``` value of first message from ```listDeliveringMessagesAsJSON``` is not changing and also not a large message.

Comment: Have you reproduced with the latest release and filed an issue as stated previously? If not, those are your next steps. Make sure to include your reproducer when you file the issue.

Comment: actually this issue is not easily reproducible locally. Issue happened in one of our deployment area. Will upgrade to latest version 2.17.0.